# How i can get the Label for a managed metadata single value column inside my event receiver

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, farm-solution

I am working on building a server-side event receiver for SharePoint on-premises 2013. now I have a single value managed metadata column named "OrderCustomerName", and I want to get the term Label, as currently if I do the following:-

```
 var ccc = currentItem["OrderCustomerName"].ToString();
```

I will get value such as "`customer ABC|[asdasdasdasdaspdasdas]`", now I do not want to rely on doing substring to extract the Label value (customer ABC), rather I am trying to access the Label property for my managed metadata column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it as `TaxonomyFieldValue`.

Check the sample implementation:

```
TaxonomyFieldValue taxFieldValue = currentItem["OrderCustomerName"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;

var label = taxFieldValue.Label;
```